# Show Image inside Viewholder item of RecycleView on Click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecycleView with having a playlist items. Now i need when user Click on an Item, A Image shown inside on the Clicked item and Hide from All Other Items.

**RecycleView Item Layout is**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
              android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemDetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemGif"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:src="@drawable/sound_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my code. this code is working fine with items are Visible on Screen. But when Items are not Visible on Screen then It gives Null Point Exception at

> viewHolder.itemGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

public void changeGif(int nowPlay)
{

```
    MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;


   for (int i=0; i<recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1;i++){
       if(i==nowPlay){

           viewHolder = (MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
           viewHolder.itemGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


       }else
       {

           viewHolder = (MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
           viewHolder.itemGif.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

       }
   }


}
```

Plz see screenshots.

[Click on Item 1 and show Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNy5l.png)

[Click on Item 2 and show Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D4PC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call changeGif method, Write this code in onBindViewHolder

```
if(i==nowPlay){
       viewHolder.itemGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }else {
       viewHolder.itemGif.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
```

and in OnclickListener write this:

```
nowPlay = position;
notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks @Divy for fast Response... it solves my problem. BUT  onBindViewHolder this Code give unexpected Result .... `if(holder.mItem.getItemDate().equalsIgnoreCase("-")){

            holder.itemDetail.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,21);
            holder.itemDetail.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.mView.setEnabled(false);

        }`    **It also Change the Color and TextSize of another position which does not meet the condition... Why..??? Plz help**

Comment: Don't take any data from holder, holder is used only for views, instead of `holder.mItem` use `mItem.getPosition(position).getItemDate().equalsIgnoreCase("-")` and reset your changes (`textSize` and `textColor`) in else condition.